# How to put a shadow to a Frameless window in Qt

Tags: qt, window, shadow, borderless

I'm trying to create a Frameless window that has a shadow under it.When we create a borderless window with **Qt::FramelessWindowHint** flag it doesn't contain a shadow.
But we can put shadows to a child widgets easy by creating a **QGraphicsDropShadowEffect** object and then pass it to the widget through **setGraphicsEffect** function. But this doesn't seem to work for QMainWindow. Please help me to put shadow to a frameless window in Qt...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using this simple hack:

---

Add a "QWidget" (say widget) to the MainWindow and move everything that's on the MainWindow to the widget. Then do this:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); //enable MainWindow to be transparent

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(5);
ui->widget->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

This seems to work for me. See:

[image: illusion of a main window having a shadow]

Comment: how did you create those graphics ?

Comment: It's been almost an year so I don't remember exactly. Perhaps I used PicPick (http://www.picpick.org/en/) for that -- took screenshot and did a little editing. It's a nice handy tool for taking screenshots and performing simple image manipulations. : )

Comment: I just tryed implementing this with PySide. Looks pretty neat but there are some big problems: 1st: the shadow is not ClickTrough! You are still clicking the window if you click the shadow :( 2nd: The shadow is part of the window. Maximizing it leaves a shadow gap (in case of really maximizing you could probably catch that and deactivate the shadow border) If you maximize horizontally or vertically only this is a little weirder... Darn. There must be a way of telling windows to use system shadow... The EA Origin game tool seems to be using this method though ^. I'd just like a bigger shadow ;]

Comment: Thanks for this hack, but I got a problem when use the transparent stuff in this senario: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63199, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @BillHoo I'll look into this, but it will be easier if you can share your code (or simple dummy code which reproduces this issue) with me. You can paste it here (https://codeshare.io/5eMzD4) OR any other way you want.

Comment: @zeFree Thanks for reply, the demo code already put into your link. You can try and see what will happen if we enabled the WA_TransluentBackground feature.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it and get back to you! And if I fix/resolve it I'll post/update the answer here.

Comment: You can also use a Frame, but make sure you enable autoFillBackground, otherwise every child of the widget/panel may get a shadow, and that's not that pretty.

Comment: @zeFree This approach is great, but issue is **that drop shadow is not click through**. Is there any way to make it click through?

Answer (score 2):

I followed exactly the instructions that were given by zeFree (using Qt/C++) and my shadow was indeed click-through (using Elementary OS Freya - I don't know if there is a different behavior between it and Ubuntu, OX or Windows)... I can't imagine why yours wasn't.

The only difference is that I made both the parent window margins and the blur radius larger, and removed the shadow offset.

Here my snippet:

```
void addDialogShadow(QWidget *target) {
    target->window()->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    target->window()->layout()->setMargin(50);
    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* ef = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect;
    ef->setBlurRadius(50);
    ef->setOffset(0);
    target->setGraphicsEffect(ef);
}
```

EDIT:
No, my windows were not clickthrough (I think I was asleep when I wrote that). Indeed even `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvent` attribute in my QDialog instance doesn't work. Grinding information on the web, I've found making this work is much more difficult than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

one not so aweseome solution would be to use the `QtCore.Qt.ToolTip` window flag instead of the `FramelessWindowHint`!

[image: at least a little shadow]

Comment: Edit: reason is the translucent attribute.

Comment: It "works" with Qt::Popup, but the window is hidden as soon as it lost focus.