# Qt QWidget as form, drop shadow effect

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, shadow, dropshadow

I have a customized qwidget with no styles which plays the role of my main window. I want to add some shadow to my QWidget, but eventually the drop shadow effect

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect shadow;
shadow.setBlurRadius(100.0);
shadow.setOffset(0,0);
.....
```

Just gives me some random black squares inside my form. Is there a way i can get my QWidget form to drop some shadow.

Comment: As in a drop shadow behind your main window?

Comment: yes i would like to have a shadow behind my form and QGraphicsDropShadowEffect is like fill's up all the inside area of my qwidget.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347776/how-to-put-a-shadow-to-a-frameless-window-in-qt

Comment: Is there any way i can replace MainWindow central widget with my own widget form without copy pasting all the contents and methods?

Comment: ok i tried it like so  `ui->setupUi(this);


    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);

    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); //enable
    //MainWindow to be transparent
     this->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint); //Set a frameless window
  //this->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint); //Set window with no title bar

    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
    effect->setBlurRadius(5);
    ui->centralwidget->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
}`

Comment: in main.cpp `MainWindow m;
    mainform *widget = new mainform();
    m.setCentralWidget(widget);
    m.show();` this gives me my widget with horrible transparency without any shadows + i cant drag it on the screen anymore, its like lays inside the mainwindow and when i try to drag it out of the mainwindow area its just dissapear