# How to get Qt Transparencies working through X11? (Or another way to make dropshadows work for X11)

Tags: qt, transparency, x11, dropshadow

I'm building a UI in Qt 5.9 that needs to run on an X11 display.   I'm trying to add drop shadows to my dialog windows - but they don't work over X11.

The approach I'm taking is from zeFree's answer in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347776/how-to-put-a-shadow-to-a-frameless-window-in-qt).  (Put everything in the window in one widget, set the window translucent, and create a dropshadow effect on the widget).

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); //enable Window to be transparent

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(5);
ui->widget->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

It works great in my redhat vm:

[image: RedHat Dropshadow]

But when I send to the X11 display I, it looks like the transparency isn't supported, and I get the shadow on black instead:

[image: X11 Dropshadow]

My question is:  Is there a way to adjust my Qt so that running this application through an X11 display will correctly show my transparencies?

Ultimately any suggestions leading to a working drop shadow on the X11 display would be great!

Comment: Do you have a compositing window manager?  That's a prerequisite to this kind of partial transparency.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know.  My target display is an Esterline display that has an IP and some unknown windows manager.   All of the fancy Qt Window styling that I get for free on redhat 7.3 is missing on this display.

Comment: If you don't get to select the window-manager, then you may well be Out Of Luck, unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like getting this style isn't an option with transparencies.   Maybe there's another way I can create the drop shadow effect.   Putting it onto my main window instead of attaching it to the dialog.   Hmm..  Perhaps making a new widget on my main window that is under the dialog - purely for the purposes of making the shadow effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this problem I ended up making a shadow object on the main window using the function below. (It puts the window in the middle of the screen and builds the shadow object) Then I do ->show() and ->hide() on the shadow object when I show and hide the window.  It's a bit of a cludge - but is the only solution I found that works through X11 on this particular touch screen.

```
QPushButton * MainWindow::positionAndShadow(QDialog* window)
{
    int xpos = SCREEN_RES_H/2 - window->size().width()/2;
    int ypos = SCREEN_RES_V/2 - window->size().height()/2;
    if (ypos - 10 > 0)
    {
        ypos -= 10;
    }
    window->setGeometry(xpos,ypos,window->size().width(),window->size().height());

    QPushButton* shadow = new QPushButton(this);
    shadow->setEnabled(false);
    shadow->setGeometry(xpos,ypos,window->size().width(),window->size().height());

    QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
    effect->setColor(QColor(40, 40, 40, 220));
    effect->setBlurRadius(15);
    shadow->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
    shadow->hide();

    return shadow;
}
```