# How to create a Qt Drop Shadow without using transparencies? (Because the window manager doesn't support it)

Tags: c++, qt, x11

I'm building a UI in Qt 5.9 that needs to run on an X11 display.   I'm trying to add drop shadows to my dialog windows - but they don't work over X11.

The approach I'm taking is from zeFree's answer in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347776/how-to-put-a-shadow-to-a-frameless-window-in-qt).  (Put everything in the window in one widget, set the window translucent, and create a dropshadow effect on the widget).

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground); //enable Window to be transparent

QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(5);
ui->widget->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

It works great in my redhat vm:

[RedHat Dropshadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGVNZ.png)

But when I send to the X11 display I, it looks like the transparency isn't supported, and I get the shadow on black instead:

[X11 Dropshadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L2Z8.png)

My question is: Is there a way to make my Dialogs project a drop shadow onto my main window instead of onto their own (transparent) background?  My application will be full screen on the X11 display so I don't need to worry about shadow effects outside of the window.

Any answer that gives me a clean way to get a drop shadow effect on this X11 display will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If your window manage doesn't support transparency you are out of luck IMO. At least with your current approach.

There is theoretically a way to fake it, provided you can grab the pixel values from the underlying window manager composite that is under your application, then draw those pixels from your application, filling the black void, with the shadow composed over that, and finally your GUI stuff.

There is also the more viable course of giving up on native windowed dialogs and fake the dialog using a regular floating widget. This has the disadvantage that it will only be able to move within the confines of your main window, but this way you will have complete control over the drawing and not fall victim to platform limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Do you have any references or examples for the approaches that don't use transparencies?   I was considering the possibility of creating a widget on my main window under the dialog.  Then I'd have to hide it when the dialog goes away.  I think for this application I can avoid the need to move the dialog - so that might simplify the scenario.

Comment: I don't, but its linux, there will probably be a way to copy pixels from the x framebuffer. Do a little searching.